# Deriving shadow position from a 2D heightmap

Tags: 2d, geometry, isometric, shadows, heightmap

I have a 2D heightmap with discrete values. Based on these values they should cast a fixed position shadow (constant angle respective to the "sun"). I can figure out how to cast it on a flat surface (0 in the heightmap). But not entirely sure how to cast it on elevated tiles (heightmap value > 0) because obviously the shadow is going to be shorter.
How do I "walk" the tiles that should be shadowed? Themselves will cast a shadow as well but that may be overridden if behind them is a taller cliff which completely shadows the current tile.
Note that I'm interested in the algorithm of determining each tile's shadow value, not the rendering side of it.
Here's an example screenshot of a game doing the same:
[image: Stronghold terrain]

Comment: Is the shadow always directly to the right as shown here, or do you have a moveable light source so we need to handle different shadowing directions?

Comment: @DMGregory For simplicity we can assume it's not moveable, directly to the right. I'd happily take a moveable light source solution as well though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can associate a "shadow height" with each cell on your map. This is the elevation something would need to have above 0 / "sea level" in order to rise out of the shadow and into the light.

You can initialize the shadow height of all tiles on the left edge of your map to zero.

Then, working across your map from left to right, each tile can compute its shadow height using its neighbouring tile to the left:

```
this.shadowHeight = max(leftNeighbour.terrainHeight + leftNeighbour.tileHeight, 
                        leftNeighbour.shadowHeight
                  ) - shadowSlope;
```

...where `shadowSlope` is a parameter you can tune to control the length of your shadows, representing the slope of the terminator between lit and shadowed regions. Low values behave like sunrise/sunset, where the light rays are almost parallel to the ground and shadows get super long. High values behave more like noon where the light rays are coming down almost vertically, making tiny shadows.

Any tile with `shadowHeight > terrainHeight` is in shadow.

If you want to simulate soft shadows, you can set the shadow darkness to be proportionate to `shadowHeight - terrainHeight`.

Result provided by [KayleMaster](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/users/106394/kaylemaster):

[image: Elevated terrain]

Comment: I'll try this out and review this answer afterwards

Comment: Works like a charm!

Comment: @KayleMaster can you shaer the whole solution?